# Need help in Multiplying the edit text value with a text view value from a custom list view in android

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom list view with a image view, 2 text view,one edit text one is for displaying brand names a string value another for displaying loyalty points, edit text for entering the quantity by the user which will be multiplied with loyalty point from text view.I have tried to multiplying the user entered value in each list item (from edit text)with the text view loyalty points value,I have implemented my own logic for multiplying it but it is not working, I have posted my code here for your reference correct me if any thing wrong in the code

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    static TextView ttv;

    ArrayList prgmName;
    public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
   public static String [] prgmNameList={"Britania","Rin","Goodrej","ITC","Nestle","Wheel","Ariel","Tide"};
    public static String [] loyal_pts={"10","5","15","25","20","18","30","32"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context=this;
ttv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tot_point);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages,loyal_pts));

    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] result;
    String [] Pts;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    int total_points;
    String con_pts;
    int lyl_pts;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages, String[] loyal_pts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        Pts=loyal_pts;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv1;
        ImageView img;
        EditText etxt;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
//        final int total_points,con_pts,lyl_pts;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        try{
            holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.etxt= (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edit_txt);
            holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tv1= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
            holder.tv1.setText(" " + Pts[position] + "pts");
            holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            System.out.println("total points"+total_points);
            holder.etxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    try {

                        lyl_pts = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Pts[position]));
                        con_pts = holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();
                        total_points = lyl_pts * Integer.parseInt(con_pts);
                        Toast.makeText(context,total_points,LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("heyy"+total_points);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: *I cant able to get the correct output* means what output currently you are getting and what you expected ?

Comment: no nothing am getting

Comment: `con_pts=holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();` means nothing, `getView()` is initial phase of creating list items. And It's empty. you need to set some text before doing this.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I expected the multiplied results, but I did not got any results

Comment: you must add `con_pts=holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();` on your `addTextChangedListener` and than after you multiply with this.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna but if set some text means, the user entered value will not be multiplied as I expected, If u have any code snipets, will be helpfull for me to understand it much more

Comment: @AbhishekPatel as per your words changed the code, now also not working no output is showing in toast

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav please update your code for now.

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav I think you need to change this  `con_pts = s.getText().toString().trim();` instead of `con_pts = holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();`

Comment: @AbhishekPatel but am creating the edittext object inside the holder class onle, how I can directly refer this like etxt.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112389/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-m-balajivaishnav).

Comment: @AbhishekPatel u there having one more problem

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is called whenever a new item is displayed on screen. at the initial phase nothing will be in your `EditText` so that you are not getting expected result from this line in `getView()` method.

```
con_pts=holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();
```

I suggest either putting some initial value at `etxt`  Or moving the logic in `afterTextChanged` like here

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        lyl_pts=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Pts[position]));
        con_pts=holder.etxt.getText().toString().trim();
        total_points = lyl_pts * Integer.parseInt(con_pts);
        System.out.println("total points"+total_points);
}
```

Comment: ex in rin am entering 5 and the loyalty poin is five so total will be 25, then in another item lets say britania am entering 2 the loyalty point is 10 so the new total will be 25+20=45 ok,

Comment: now if I delete the value from britania that is 2 now the total value must be 25 only still showing 45, now u understood the problem

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav ohh I am really sorry that I didn't notice your reply, Did you solve it now ?